# Sort replies and new thread by date

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sorting

I want my board to sort threads in the order that new threads are displayed at the top until another new thread is created or a reply has been made in another thread. If this happens the thread will go down from 1 to 2 and so on.

However the code I'm using right now only does this: if a new thread is created it will be displayed at the bottom, but if you make a reply it will go to the top. So all that's being needed to fix is making it showing the newest thread created on the top aswell.

```
    SELECT b.id, b.name, b.subject, b.maintext, b.ip, b.date, b.img, b.replycount, MAX(r.date)
FROM 
    board b
    LEFT JOIN reply r ON r.id = b.id

GROUP BY b.id, b.date
ORDER BY GREATEST(b.date, MAX(r.date)) DESC
LIMIT 50;
```

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the tables' columns?

Comment: Something like that I suppose.

Comment: Why are you storing the threads and replies in different tables? If you store them all in one table you'll have less problems with things like this an if you index the table correctly you'll not have any performance issues for large data sets.

Comment: @AndrewWillis: Different things have different needs. Posts may have title, replies may not. Posts may have tags, replies may not. You can't have everything in one table.

Comment: Yes but you could enable the title and tags to be NULL in the database. Just because it is able to be NULL doesn't mean that every value will be NULL and if your server scripting is good enough this wouldn't be a hindrance either. It also allows for simpler 'quoting' queries when users want to quote each other, for another example.

Comment: Also tags should be stored in a separate table with a 'many for many' link table anyway.

Comment: @Andrew: And in that way (threads and replies in same table and a many-to-many link table for tags), how will you enforce that only threads can have tags and replies do not?

Comment: By not enabling people to do it. Like I said. Your database does what it's told. Write good, secure script for processing and let your database do what it's there for: storing data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`greatest` will [return null](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/comparison-operators.html#function_greatest) if any of the arguments are null => i suggest using coalesce, if you care about new threads and new replies, but not about updates to the original thread:

```sql
order by coalesce(MAX(r.date), b.date)
```

---

if you care about the updates too (so b.date can be greater than max(r.date)):

```sql
order by greatest(b.date, coalesce(MAX(r.date), b.date))
```

Comment: But this won't find the `GREATEST` of the two dates, will it?

Comment: @deathApril It could if posts can be edited and that `date` stores last_update_date.

Comment: @ypercube good point, but that case is actually out of scope of the business specificaton - "another new thread is created or a reply has been made"

Comment: I agree, your query is probably what the OP wants. But I prefer to explicitely write in the answer why, when the logic is changed (as in this case the OP's wording matches your logic while his code implies somethign else).